# Django onetoone relationship with User not working with query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

My model is like this

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,default=None,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,null=True)
```

i am trying to get through models using shell but getting the empty query.
I tried this

```
>>> u1=User.objects.get(username='gautam')
>>>u1
<User: gautam> 
>>> Profile.objects.get(user=u1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
exec(code, self.locals)
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/home/gautam/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/gautam/.local/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
self.model._meta.object_name
homes_login.models.DoesNotExist: Profile matching query does not 
exist.
```

I am tring to get the user for that profile.

Comment: This can happen. Note that `OneToOneField` in fact does *not* mean that every `User` has a a `Profile`, it means you constructed a `ForeignKey`, with a `unique=True` constraint, such that two `Profile`s can *not* point to the same `User`.

Comment: hey thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This profile is simply not created. Setting an `OneToOne` relation doesn't guarantee that profile will exist for each user. To overcome that, you should simply create new profile, like this:

```
>>> Profile.objects.create(user=u1)
```

To automate process of getting existing profile or creating new one, you can use `get_or_create` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GwynBleidD you really solved my problem